# Is there a way to view a detailed breakdown of xaml markup at runtime like you can with websites?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

Like when you go to any webpage and you hit F12, you can see the breakdown of the HTML elements, highlight an element, see all of the properties of it and how it affects it.

If you could do that some how in WPF, it would make learning it soooo much easier for a visual learner like my self. I'm constantly making small tweaks, hitting start to see what's changed and doing it over and over (When design view isn't accurate because of dynamically created objects and such). Putting in Console.WriteLines to give me back actualwidths of specific elements. It's tedious and I know there's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) is your friend in analyzing and modifying wpf on the fly.

Comment: Though the other answers work for VS2015, I'm going to accept this answer because it works for VS2013. (I see now that I didn't specify it directly in my question but through a tag.)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from Snoop and if you want it to be more IDE integrated, VS2015's Visual Tree is another option.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/02/24/introducing-the-ui-debugging-tools-for-xaml.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **WPF Tree Visualizer**, you can see more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409789.aspx).

Alternatively, Visual Studio 2015 introduced the **Live Visual Tree**, this will allow you to inspect XAML elements whilst debugging. More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx).

Comment: Edit: This is great, I'm trying out the live visual tree now. Can you tell me why some properties can be changed whilst being run in debug and some cannot. (e.g. I see I can change the width and margin of a button while running, but I cannot change the background or padding)

Comment: It is quite beautiful. I'm guessing there's some limitations to what properties can be edited, I'll do some research if I get time and try to find out why.